# Installing LAMP Server in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lamp, drupal

I used sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ because someone in this forum said

***"This will install Apache, MySQL, PHP and also configure it for you. All you need to supply is a password for MySQL and you'll have a running local webserver in a manner of minutes."***

During the LAMP Server installation I was asked to create an MySQL Root User Password.  At this point how do I know if everything installed and is configured properly ?

What I would like to do next is install Drupal 8 so that I can begin building a site offline for the purposes of a project.

Pls let me know your thoughts.

Thank you !

joeyz101

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have followed the steps properly installing LAMP stack. To make things simpler and easy, you can check the service status.

For Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

for PHP

```
php -v
```

will print all the required information with php version. If you need more, you can simply even create `info.php` page along with below information, while placing it on the server root.

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

As for MySQL, you can check with;

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

Installing Drupal should be straight forward as installing other framework such as wordpress, Joomla... etc. However you need to refer to a document on installing drupal and place them right at the root of where apache's `httpd.conf` points to.

Hope this helps!